# jQuery Templates not rendering a class name

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery templates (jquery.tmpl.js) to render content on a webpage and am experiencing an unexpected result.

A couple of the properties in my JSON object are

```
CanMovePrevious    false
CanSkipQuestion    false
```

And here's a snippet from my template which is producing the unexpected result:

```
{{if CanMovePrevious}}
    <a id="previous"><span>${PreviousButtonText}</span></a>
{{/if}}
{{if CanSkipQuestion}}
    <a id="next"><span>${NextButtonText}</span></a>
{{else}}
    <a id="next" class="hideV"><span>${NextButtonText}</span></a>
{{/if}}
```

I've included the *CanMovePrevious* condition because this works as expected: in the case of the above JSON data the *CanMovePrevious* elements are *not* rendered.

However, in the case of the *CanSkipQuestion* condition, and using the above JSON data, the markup is actually rendered as

```
<a id="next" class=""><span>Next</span></a>
```

Which is kind of a mix between the two options.

If the *CanSkipQuestion* property is *true* then the markup rendered is as expected, *i.e.*

```
<a id="next"><span>Next</span></a>
```

If I change the name of the class then it appears as expected, *i.e.*

```
<a id="next" class="myClass"><span>Next</span></a>
```

Can anyone explain why the class name "hideV" is not being rendered when *CanSkipQuestion* is set to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code 
`{{if CanSkipQuestion}}`
 is only making sure that `CanSkipQuestion` **exists**, if it does it will go inside and create HTML.

If you want your condition to work on the value of `CanSkipQuestion` you need to change conditions in template like this `{{if CanSkipQuestion == true}}` .

Comment: Tak for din svar, @Danish - That sounds reasonable, but it doesn't explain why an empty class attribute is rendered. I've since moved on from this, but it might have been the case that Firebug was showing the empty class attribute, even though it wasn't in the DOM or the original HTML.